# Running through Python tutorial and stuck at functions

Tags: python, function

I'm trying to create a very basic function, but I can't seem to do it.  Please see the instructions I need to follow:

> 1. First, `def` a function called `cube` that takes an argument called `number`. Don't forget the parentheses and the colon!
> 2. Make that function return the cube of that number (i.e. that number multiplied by itself and multiplied by itself once again).
> 3. Define a second function called `by_three` that takes an argument called `number`.
> 4. if that number is divisible by `3`, `by_three` should call `cube(number)` and return its result. Otherwise, `by_three` should
>      `return False`.

My code so far is:

```
number = raw_input("Enter number")

def cube(number):
    answer = number**3
    return(answer)

def by_three(answer):
    if answer % 3 == 0:
        return(answer)
    else:
        return(False)
```

Please tell me what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: You've defined the functions, but you never actually call either one on the number you input.

Comment: "if that number is divisible by 3, by_three should call cube(number) and return its result. Otherwise, by_three should return False." Well, return cube(number) then!

Comment: You're being confused by naming variables `answer` in both functions. Change the name of the argument in `by_three` and you'll see they're unrelated!

Comment: Thank you for all the quick replies....return cube(answer) resolved it.  Not sure why i missed that :(

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You forgot one detail for step 4; you need to return the result for `cube()`, you are returning `answer` unaltered.

Rather than:

```
if answer % 3 == 0:
    return(answer)
```

use:

```
if answer % 3 == 0:
    return cube(answer)
```

Note that `return` is not itself a function; it is a keyword. Just put a space after it and you don't have to put the expression whose result is to be returned to the caller in parentheses.